# regex match can not match well in C#

Tags: c#

I use VS 2017 in windows 7.

The regex match can not work for my code. Although the content has the string I want to match, it can not be matched by my code.

I have tried to use regex.Match() method in a while loop to match the resp.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"CHIP*");
var match = regex.Match(resp);
if (match.Success)
 {

   textBox1.AppendText(match.Groups[1].Value);
 }
```

Although resp contains "CHIP......", textBox1 shows nothing.

Comment: Just *match.Value* is enough, no need to specify group.

Comment: As @akg179 said - you didn't define any capture groups in the regex, so there's only the default group with index 0.
Also - "CHIP*" is _likely_ not what you want. I assume you want "CHIP followed by anything", but this means "CHI followed by P, P repeated 0 to N times".

Comment: what should be like instead of CHIP*?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this regex string. "`^CHIP(.+)"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `match.Groups[1].Value`

Instead you should be using `match.Groups[0].Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if (match.Success)
 {

   textBox1.AppendText(match.Value);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `CHIP*` will match the letters `CHI` followed by `P` 0->infinite times.

If what you're wanting it to behave like is a wildcard expression (`CHIP` followed by anything else) then you want your expression to be:

`CHIP(.*)`

The brackets put that part in a match group so you can get just that part of the value, the `.` matches any character and the `*` means '0 or more times'. If you want to require something after the word CHIP (making a suffix mandatory) then you'd replace the `*` with a `+`.